# Does "peculiar" imply "unusual"/"hard to expect"?

Tags: meaning, connotation

When something is called *peculiar* or *having a peculiarity* what does that mean? Does it just mean it has some specific features or does it mean that those specific features are unusual, not normally expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Pecularity* means "an odd or unusual feature or habit", but also "a characteristic or quality that is distinctive of a particular person or place".

> For all her peculiarities, he finds her personality quite endearing.
>   Her essays characterized decency as a British peculiarity.

*Peculiar* means "strange or odd", but also "unusual", or (in *peculiar to*) "belonging exclusively to".

> Her accent was a peculiar mixture of Cockney and Irish.
>   The air hung with an antiseptic aroma peculiar to hospitals.

*Peculiar* and *having a peculiarity* have both the meanings you supposed.

Informally, *peculiar* means also *unwell*: *she felt a little peculiar for a while*.

**<sub>[Reference: the *New Oxford American English*.]</sub>**

Comment: The sense of "characteristic of" is now rather literary: in informal speech it almost always has the connotation of being strange or wrong.

Comment: I think you could say "How peculiar!" to mean that something was unexpected in the same way that [Alice](http://intranet.dalton.org/ms/alice/7.html) said "Curiouser and curiouser!"