# Is "peculiar" completely interchangeable with "strange"?

Tags: synonyms

Is *peculiar* completely interchangeable with *strange*? can both be used in exactly the same contexts?

Comment: Related: [Does “peculiar” imply “unusual”/“hard to expect”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13975/does-peculiar-imply-unusual-hard-to-expect)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Peculiar* can be used as a synonym for *strange*. However, *peculiar* originally has the meaning "particular to a given place or time; unique", and it is sometimes used that way today. And the connotations of the words still differ: *strange* carries a slight hint of disapproval, while *peculiar* suggests curiosity and uniqueness more than abnormality.

Comment: I love this! Every word is different in some way.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience there is a slight connotational difference.

Both words refer to something that is unfamiliar to the observer. However, each word implies a slightly different reaction to the unfamiliar object or person. *Peculiar* tends to imply that the unfamiliar object draws interest and further scrutiny. Conversely a *strange* object inspires unease or possibly repulsion.

In essence, *peculiar* means unfamiliar in a good way, and *strange* means unfamiliar in a bad way.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what Oxford has to say on this one. Here are the links: [Strange](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/strange), and [Peculiar](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peculiar).

Strange conveys the notion of *unfamiliarity* or *oddity*.

Peculiar on the other hand signifies *particular*, *special*, or *abnormal* (anything that deviates from the normal or the expected). The etymology of this word is noteworthy. Its meaning as `strange` is dated later (17<sup>th</sup> cent.) by the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Example:
In America, in December, peculiar decorations are publicly displayed.